# What is the correct way to ensure OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter closes an EntityManager session for a StreamingResponseBody?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

For **synchronous** requests, [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java#L193) appears to close the `EntityManager` correctly.

For **asynchronous** requests such as when a REST controller returns a `StreamingResponseBody`, `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` appears to rely upon [AsyncRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/AsyncRequestInterceptor.java#L96) to close the `EntityManager`.

The `AsyncRequestInterceptor` however, will only close the `EntityManager` if an [error or timeout](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/AsyncRequestInterceptor.java#L97) occurs, which in my application, results in a HikariCP connection leak.

To work around this problem, I have created a copy of `AsyncRequestInterceptor` and modified its `closeSession()` method so that it unconditionally closes the JPA session:

```
private void closeSession() {
    // if (this.timeoutInProgress || this.errorInProgress) {
    //    logger.debug("Closing Hibernate Session after async request timeout/error");
        SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(this.sessionHolder.getSession());
    // }
}
```

What is the correct way to ensure that the `EntityManager` is closed, when processing is Async, i.e. when returning a `StreamingResponseBody`?

NOTE: I have tried explicitly closing an injected instance of the `EntityManager`, but the JPA connection remains active in the HikariCP:

```
@Transactional
@RestController
public class MyController {
  
  @PersistenceContext
  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  @GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public StreamingResponseBody stream() {
    return outputStream -> {
      try {
        // perform read-only operations with the entity manager

      } finally {
        entityManager.close();
      }
    };
  }
}
```